# only users can delete own data in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

l want edit my rules in firebase database , l want make only the user he can delete or edit data belongs to them , not other users can edit or delete .

my database

[image]

l did rules like that , but it is same any user can update or delete

```
{
    "rules": {
        "report": {
             ".read": "auth != null",
                            ".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just copy paste [authorization part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization) from official documentation:

> The Firebase Database Rules include built-in variables and functions
>   that allow you to refer to other paths, server-side timestamps,
>   authentication information, and more. Here's an example of a rule that
>   grants write access for authenticated users to `/users/<uid>/`, where
>    is the ID of the user obtained through Firebase Authentication.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When we come to Your question:

1) So Your document must keep `userId` field to relate it to owner

2) You have to add such rule to it:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "report": {
             ".read": "auth != null",
             ".write": "auth != null && ( (data.exists() && data.userId === auth.uid) || !data.exists() || !newData.exists() )"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: l got error when l am try to save rules for your second answer . `Error saving rules - Line 5: No such method/property 'userId`'.

Comment: @pabloescobar I said to add `userId` to Your data first

Comment: could you please edit your answer again ? , because when l am try to edit l got error  . thank you

Comment: @pabloescobar it's already in my answer: **So Your document must keep userId field to relate it to owner**

Comment: it is same , error `Error saving rules - Line 7: Unknown variable '$username'.; Line 8: No such method/property 'userId'.`

Comment: `{
"rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null",
  "report":{
    "userId": {
        ".read": "$username === auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && ( (data.exists() && data.userId === auth.uid) || !data.exists() || !newData.exists() )"

      }  
  
   }
  }
}`